# Liquid: Replace a String with an Expression

Tags: string, object, liquid

I need to replace a string with an expression. 
The code features three string replace scenarios. For the first two, the strings are replaced with alternate strings, which works perfectly.
However for the third scenario, I need to replace the string "channel" with an expression instead: {{ booking.channel }}. My code is incorrect for the third instance only, and I have not found a solution.

```html
<div class="row">
          <div class="left title">Source</div>
          <div class="right">{{ booking.source | replace: "app", "Front Desk" | replace: "widget", "Website" | replace: "channel", {{ booking.channel }} }}</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `{{ }}` arround `booking.channel` as you are already inside other `{{ }}`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="left title">Source</div>
    <div class="right">{{ booking.source | replace: "app", "Front Desk" | replace: "widget", "Website" | replace: "channel", booking.channel }}</div>
```